# Rows.Count = 1 when returned dataset consists of an empty row

Tags: c#, sql-server, dataset, rowcount

My query does not return anything but an empty row, since there is no records that meet all the criteria of my query. However, Rows.Count is 1 instead of 0. Here is my query:

```
SELECT LicenseID 
FROM LICENSES 
WHERE LicenseType = @LicenseType 
    AND DriverID = @DriverID 
    AND CarID IN(
        SELECT CarID 
        FROM CARS 
        WHERE CarSerial = @CarSerial 
            AND DriverID = @DriverID
    ) AND LicenseID IS NOT NULL 
    AND ((StartDate <= CONVERT(DATETIME, @EndDate)) 
    AND (EndDate >= CONVERT(DATETIME, @StartDate)))
```

Here is my C# if statement condition that for some reason keeps being true due to row count, even though there is no record meeting criteria:

```
if (ds != null && ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
```

The database used is SQL Server. This previously seemed to work correctly under Oracle.

Comment: An empty row is still a row. Try some isnull in the sql?

Comment: If there were no records that meet all the criteria of your query, then your query would be returning ***zero*** rows, not an empty row.  So, obviously, you are doing something wrong.

Comment: If you are getting 1 row returned, can you see what the value is? Maybe that will help troubleshoot. Basically, when that line of code is being executed, it has a row of data, so find out what it is.

Comment: This code "if (ds != null && ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)" returns an ERROR if database has a null value.

Comment: @Trey - My SQL has the isnull already.

Comment: @Jason - Yes, the value is an empty string.

Comment: I should have posted as an answer :-)

Answer (score 0):

To Avoid ERROR:

```
if (ds.Tables.Count > 0)
 {
      if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
      {
         //Then Return a value here or Get the date
                foreach (DataRow dr in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
                {
                    String getFirstRow = dr[0].ToString();
                    //And so on........
                }
      }
      else
      { 
            //Return value if no rows found.
      }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

what I needed to add was just an additional check for "LicenseID <> ''". "LicenseID IS NOT NULL" was not enough since there has been a record meeting all criteria but having LicenseID = "". I believe this has not been an issue with Oracle database, but turned out to be an issue after switching to SQL Server. Thanks for all your comments and suggestions.